# Bar plotting of 99 keys dictionary (key = event, value = number_of_occurence)

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm beginning to learn matplotlib and I do not have much time to browse stackoverflow or the matplotlib doc. I think my issue is fairly simple but I cannot find a way to do it.

I have a dictionary with 99 keys representing events with the value being the number of occurence of that event.

dict = {'event_1' : '2' , 'event_2' : '14' , ... , 'event_99' : '5' }

I can plot it with this line :

```
plt.bar(dict.keys(), dict.values(), width)
```

[image]

But as you can see, it looks really bad.

What I would like to do is to color the bars based on events and get them as a legend to the side of the plot. Is this possible?
Or do you think of a better way to represent the data?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to do an awful amount of digging. If you check out the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) there's a `color` keyword that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found that information before but I was wondering if there was some sort of automatic coloring based on bars directly. I did an array with rainbow colors, it's okey-ish. Graph seems happy now.